# Xcode: The debugger stops at the breakpoints inside some files, but doesn't stop at other

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

I'm trying to debug a C++ application on Xcode 10 with the code organized under a group called src, with the following simplified *Project Navigation* hierarchy:

```
src/
  +--- file1.cpp
  +--- file2.cpp
  +--- subgroup1/
         +---file3.cpp
         +---file4.cpp
```

file1.cpp and file2.cpp use functions and objects found inside file3.cpp and file4.cpp. While the debugger properly stops at breakpoints found at file1.cpp and file2.cpp (the files at the root of the `src` group), it completely ignores the breakpoints in the methods/functions of the sub-group files and simply goes on with the breakpoints at the top level files.

Comment: Disclaimer: I never used XCode, so I may not know the common issues with it, but, typically, debuggers, may not like if the source code doesn't match the executable code (the code was changed after the last compilation, and not recompiled, before debugging).

Comment: that's a very interesting point @AlgirdasPreidžius! XCode seems unable to detect changes in the file in general. Checking online there seem to be reports of an issue with the "New build system" found in XCode10 but despite switching back to the "Legacy System" and deleting all DerivedData, I still can't get it to monitor these files